# React Native : Pinch Zoom not working properly while sliding images

Tags: react-native, pinchzoom

I am integrating pinch zoom functionality to my react native app but it is not working properly as expected. I need pinch zoom functionality while sliding images

I have tried various libraries(ReactNativeZoomableView, react native pan zoom, PinchGesturehandler) but nothing work as expected.

Here's my code :

```
import ImageViewer from 'react-native-image-zoom-viewer';

{this.state.sessionsdetails.length > 0 ? (
                    <View style={{ flex: 1.7 }}>
                        <ImageViewer
                            key={this.state.counter}
                            ref={viewPager => (this.viewPager = viewPager)}
                            renderHeader={() => {

                            }}
                            renderIndicator={() => {

                            }}
                            loadingRender={() => {
                                return (
                                    <ActivityIndicator style={{ alignSelf: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', height: '100%' }} size="small" color={Colors.primary} />
                                )
                            }}
                            index={this.state.index} imageUrls={this.state.images} style={{ flex: 1 }} onChange={(index) => {
                                this._onChangePage(index)
                            }} />
```

Imageviewer library works best of all libraries but it doesn't reset while sliding and also during zoomed in sliding image doesn't work properly.

Let me know if there are other ways of doing so. Any help would be appreciated.